# How to create a three column header with multiple rows on sides and Huge text in the middle

Tags: header-footer

What I am trying to achieve is best said with this picture that I made in Microsoft Word and an image editor:

[image]

It would be nice (but not necessary) if the height of the middle text matched the height of the two side rows together.

I fiddled with `multicol`, `parcolumns`, and other techniques for quite some time, but couldn't get this layout. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Which document class are you using? Do you want this header for all pages of your document or just for even/odd pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `fancyhdr` package to set the header:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{3ex}{\large \bfseries John Johnson Smith}}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{1234 1 St.\\
City, State 12345}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\small 123-456-7890\\
johnsmith@example.com}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
‎\end{document}‎
```